# Update document from inside another document - mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have the following code in a collection:

```
class Author(Agent): 

    def foo(self):
        self.find_another_document_and_update_it(ids)
        self.processed = True
        self.save()

    def find_another_document_and_update_it(self, ids):
        for id in ids:
            documentA = Authors.objects(id=id)
            documentA.update(inc__mentions=1)
```

Inside `find_another_document_and_update_it()` I query the database and retrieve a document A. and then I increment a counter in A. Then in `foo()`, after calling `find_another_document_and_update_it()`, I also save the current document lets say B. The problem is that although I can see that the counter in A is actually increased when `self.save()` is called, document A is reset to its old value. I guess the problem is to do with a concurrency issue and how MongoDB deals with it. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoEngine 0.5 `save` only updates fields that have changed - prior it saved the whole document, which would have meant the previous update in `find_another_document_and_update_it` would have been overwritten.  In general and as with all things python, its better to be explicit - so you might want to use `update` to update a document.

You should be able to update all mentions with a single update:

```
Authors.objects(id__in=ids).update(inc__mentions=1)
```

Regardless, the best way to update would be to call the global updates after `self.save()`.  That way the mentions are only incremented after you've processed and saved any changes.